# Managing 3D point data

Tags: c#, algorithm

Can this be optimized?

```
static internal Point3D[] _data;
static internal Point3dTree _kd;

static internal int _interpolation_count = 0;
static internal int _iteration_count = 0;
static Dictionary<int, Point3D> Interpolated_Values = new Dictionary<int, Point3D>();

static internal int _threasindex;
static internal double[] _threasholds = new double[]
{
    0.5,
    1.0,
    1.5,
    20.5
};

static internal double Interpolate(double x, double x0, double x1, double y0, double y1)
{
    if ((x1 - x0) == 0)
        return (y0 + y1) / 2;

    return y0 + (x - x0) * (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (new ProceduralTimer("Loading data"))
        _data = LasReader.GetData(@"C:\WindowsLP\SAMPLE_PROJECT\brisport2\area_cov.las");
    using (new ProceduralTimer("Bulding Kd tree"))
        _kd = new Point3dTree(_data, false);

    List<Point3D> InterpolatedData = _data.ToList();
    _data = null;

    using (new ProceduralTimer("Processing"))
    {
        int i = 0;
        var neighbours = new List<Point3D>();
        for (; i < InterpolatedData.Count; i++)
        {
        @rescan:
            neighbours = _kd.NearestNeighbours(new KdTreeNode<Point3D>(InterpolatedData[i]), _threasholds[_threasindex % _threasholds.Length]);

            if (neighbours.Count < 4 && _threasindex < _threasholds.Length)
            {
                _threasindex++;
                _iteration_count++;
                goto rescan;
            }
            else
            {
                if (neighbours.Count >= 4)
                {
                    double[] xvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.X).ToArray();
                    double[] yvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.Y).ToArray();
                    double[] zvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.Z).ToArray();

                    Point3D pt = new Point3D();
                    pt.X = Math.Round(Interpolate(InterpolatedData[i].X, xvalues[0], xvalues[1], xvalues[2], xvalues[3]), 2);
                    pt.Y = Math.Round(Interpolate(InterpolatedData[i].Y, yvalues[0], yvalues[1], yvalues[2], yvalues[3]), 2);
                    pt.Z = Math.Round(Interpolate(InterpolatedData[i].Z, zvalues[0], zvalues[1], zvalues[2], zvalues[3]), 2);

                    Interpolated_Values[i] = pt;

                    _interpolation_count++;
                }

                _threasindex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: since your GOTO statement just points to the top of the for loop, replace it with `continue`..that is what it is for.

Comment: @RobertSnyder: `continue` will increment `i`.  The `goto` doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

Since you provide no description of your algorithm whatsoever, nor do you provide any implementation of classes you use, i take it you are sure that there is nothing left to optimize. Because normally if you feel that it works too slow, you should start by optimizing the algorithm itself and implementations of its basic calculations.
By optimizing this bit of code you provided, you will probably win some milliseconds in a long run, but this kind of micro optimization is not normally necessary. But oh well.

1. In your `Interpolate` method you calculate x1 - x0 twice. This value can be assigned to local variable. (This is probably optimized anyway at some point of compilation, but better safe than sorry.)
2. `List<Point3D> InterpolatedData = _data.ToList();` -- What is `_data`? Is it an `IEnumerable<T>`? Is it possible to refactor `LasReader.GetData` so it returns `IList<T>` straight away, so there is no unnecessary copying from one collection to another?
3. You should probably keep `goto` since it's quite fast, but again this is the kind of micro optimization one dont normally need. So for the sake of people who might read your code you could refactor it to an inner `while`loop.
4. `var neighbours = new List<Point3D>();` -- what is the point in this assignment? if you want to create an empty list in case  `InterpolatedData.Count == 0` then wrap it in an `if` statement, otherwise you are wasting resources  to create a List you dont really need.
5. I see no reason to do this:

   ```
   double[] xvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.X).ToArray();
   double[] yvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.Y).ToArray();
   double[] zvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.Z).ToArray();
   ```

   Why copy? Why can't you simply access `neighbours[i].X`?
6. it looks like there is clearly a room for some parallel calculations. **That should be your main concern**; that can give a real boost to speed. But without seeing full code, it's hard to tell the way to best implement multithreading into your calculations. So it is something for you to think about.